# CSS doesn't work when running program but it does work when I'm not

Tags: java, html, css, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

When I run my code the CSS for my html doesn't apply.

[Page with code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK4pQ.png)

But when I use the built in HTML displayer for chrome in intellij it does work.

[Page without code running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Htwm.png)

We're programming in java and using the Spring framework to make a website. Been trying everything I could find on the subject.

It does work fine however if I don't use a stylesheet but rather implement the style directly in the html, but I don't want to clutter all the html pages with the style.

In my html I've used:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css" />
</head>
```

I've also tested other working CSS styles to see if it would help so I know it's not that.

Edit:

The code in my controller

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String home(Model model) {

    if (currentUser==null) {
        return "home";
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("userOnline",currentUser);
        return "adminView/aHome";
    }
}
```

The css doesn't work on any of the pages, but I'm starting with front page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="navbar">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="login">Login</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[The structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhUZv.png)

When I run my program on http://localhost:8888/ it doesn't work, but intellij has a function that shows me the page in chrome where it sends me to http://localhost:63342/demo/templates/home.html?_ijt=kd3vqt392jk8ggqv8ctthtemsi#contact , when it does that it works.

Edit 2:

Nothing I tried worked but it works now, no idea why.

Comment: Without seeing your code nobody can help you..however try slash before /static/style.css

Comment: I have elaborated further.

Comment: try `href="./static/style.css"` or `href="../static/style.css"`

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely something with the filepath. If you're using HTML5, do this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/style.css">
</head>
```

If this doesn't work, check your file path to the CSS document. It could be that you're missing a `/`, `/static/style.css`, or `../static/style.css` etc. It's hard to fix the problem without seeing the code etc, but this is the only solution I can come up with right now.

Comment: I've tried that, it didn't work. I've elaborated the problem further, but thanks anyway.